# Easiest way to show month number and year after certain month year upto current month and year

Tags: php

I have to show how many users signed up each month after certain month and certain year upto current month and current year.

For example: if we take data from 3rd month of 2015.

So the output will be like:

```
03/2015
04/2015
05/2015
...
and so on upto
12/2015
01/2016
as currently 1st month of 2016 is running.
```

Any help??

Here is some code I have tried:

```
$c_month = date('m');
$c_year = date('Y');
$year_array = array("2015","2016","2017","2018","2019","2020","2021");



foreach($year_array as $y_a){
   for($i=1;$i<=12;$i++){
   if(($i == 1 || $i == 2) && $y_a == '2015'){
       continue;
   }
   if($i > $c_month && $y_a == $c_year){
   break 2;
 }
 $chnge_i = strlen($i);
                    if ($chnge_i == 1) {
                        $put_o = '0' . $i;
                    }
                    else{
                        $put_o = $i;
                    }
 echo $put_o.'/'.$y_a.'<br>';
}
}
```

It is giving correct values except if current month number is 12 and also i don't think this is the best way to do it.

Comment: can you show us some of your code to provide context for the solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) and [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) to do this.

```
$start=strtotime('2015-03-01');
while ($start <= time()){
    echo date('m/Y',$start) . "\n";
    $start=strtotime('+1 month', $start);
}
```

Output:

```
03/2015
04/2015
05/2015
06/2015
07/2015
08/2015
09/2015
10/2015
11/2015
12/2015
01/2016
```

Note: this is only one of the ways.

Important Note: remember to set timezone (i would prefer UTC) [date_default_timezone_set](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php)

Answer (score 0):

you should do the difference like below

```
//previous date
$start    = (new DateTime('2013-12-02'))->modify('first day of this month');
// current date
$end      = (new DateTime('2015-12-06'))->modify('first day of this month');
$interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 month');
    $period   = new DatePeriod($start, $interval, $end);

foreach ($period as $dt) {
    echo $dt->format("m/Y") . "<br>\n";
}
```

Hope this helps.